# Duda global posicionamiento mouse

Tags: html, canvas

Estoy intentando realizar un ejercicio donde tengo que crear un 3 en raya con un `canvas` de de 3x3 sencillo; el problema es que necesitaría saber como crear un evento que capture la posición del ratón y en función de donde esté nos diga la casilla.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
/* Función representarMatriz  aki le ponemos al funcion k emos creado abajo ene l for*/
function representarMatriz(x, y, lado) {
    /*
    Representación en el canvas
    */

    /* Definición de las propiedades de los trazos */
    contextoCanvas.strokeStyle = "black";
    contextoCanvas.lineWidth = 2;

    var xInicio = x;
    var yInicio = y;
    var longitudLado = lado;

    /* Inicio del recorrido en línea punteada */
    contextoCanvas.beginPath();

    /* Punto de inicio del trazo (x, y) */
    contextoCanvas.moveTo(xInicio, yInicio);

    /* Representación del trazo alto horizontal */
    contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio + longitudLado, yInicio);

    /* Representación del trazo derecho vertical */
    contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio + longitudLado, yInicio + longitudLado);

    /* Representación del trazo bajo horizontal */
    contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio, yInicio + longitudLado);

    /* Representación del trazo izquierda vertical */
    contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio, yInicio);

    /* Fin de recorrido en línea punteada (opcional) */
    contextoCanvas.closePath();

    /* Representación efectiva */
    contextoCanvas.stroke();

}

function dibujaCuadrado (){


    /* Definición de la ubicación del canvas */
    var ubicacionCanvas = document.getElementById("nuestroCanvas"); 

    /* Definición del contexto del canvas (2D) */
    var contextoCanvas = ubicacionCanvas.getContext("2d");



    /* Definición de las propiedades de los trazos */
    contextoCanvas.strokeStyle = "black"; 
    contextoCanvas.lineWidth = 4;
    contextoCanvas.fillStyle = "blue"; // esto es para k nos pinte el recuadro

    //definicion de variablespara dibujar en el tablero

    var xInicio= 120;
    var yInicio = 220;
    var longitudLado = 60;

    /*emepezamos a dibujar*/

    /* Inicio del recorrido en línea punteada */
    contextoCanvas.beginPath();
    /* Punto de inicio del trazo (x, y) */
    contextoCanvas.moveTo(xInicio, yInicio);

    /* Representación del trazo alto horizontal */
    contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio + longitudLado, yInicio);

    /* Representación del trazo derecho vertical */
    contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio + longitudLado, yInicio + longitudLado);

    /* Representación del trazo bajo horizontal */
    contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio, yInicio + longitudLado);

    /* Representación del trazo izquierda vertical */
    contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio, yInicio);

    contextoCanvas.closePath(); 
    /* Representación efectiva */
    contextoCanvas.stroke();
    /*con esto nos pondra el color k le eemos dicho arriba*/
    contextoCanvas.fill();

}

function dibujaCirculo (){


    /* Definición de la ubicación del canvas */
    var ubicacionCanvas = document.getElementById("nuestroCanvas"); 

    /* Definición del contexto del canvas (2D) */
    var contextoCanvas = ubicacionCanvas.getContext("2d");

    /*definimos el centro del circulo y su radio*/
    var xCentroCirculo = 250;
    var yCentroCirculo = 250; 
    var radioCirculo = 30;




    /* Definición de las propiedades de los trazos */
    contextoCanvas.strokeStyle = "black"; 
    contextoCanvas.lineWidth = 2;
    contextoCanvas.fillStyle = "green"; // esto es para k nos pinte el recuadro


    /*emepezamos a dibujar*/

    contextoCanvas.beginPath();
    contextoCanvas.arc(xCentroCirculo, yCentroCirculo , radioCirculo , 0 , 2*Math.PI , false);
    /*con esto nos pondra el color k le eemos dicho arriba*/
    contextoCanvas.fill();
    contextoCanvas.stroke();
}


/* Definición de la ubicación del canvas */
var ubicacionCanvas = document.getElementById("nuestroCanvas"); /* simplemente le decimos donde colocamos nuestro canvas es decir
yo voy aponer el contenido de nuestro canvas en esta variable*/


/* Definición del contexto del canvas (2D) */
var contextoCanvas = ubicacionCanvas.getContext("2d");/* esto es un metodo de canvas llamado getcontext quee s para poner el contexto
osea si keremos 2d o 3d */



for (linea = 1; linea <= 3; linea++) {
/* Representación de los 5 cuadrados de la línea numeroLinea de la matriz */
    for (columna = 1; columna <= 3; columna++) {
            representarMatriz(columna * 100, linea * 100, 100); /*vale esta linea nos dibuja el cuadrado*/
        }
}
```

```html
<h1>ejercicio 2 tema 18</h1>


<canvas id="nuestroCanvas" width="1000" height="800"> <!-- estoes por si el navegor es muy antiguo y no reconoce canvas-->
        Atención su navegador no soporta el elemento Canvas
    </canvas>
```

Gracias un saludo.

Comment: ¿hablamos de un canvas en qué lenguaje/entorno/framework?

Comment: Hola jach que tal . pues soy muy novato pero vamos html5 , css y javaScript , se crear el canvas y la estructura y el circulo y cudrado el problema es hacer clik dentro del cuadro de la matriz y que me lo rellene

Comment: Joel, todo bien, ¿y tu? En ese caso, sugiero que incluyas el código que tienes actualmente como parte de la pregunta. Utiliza un _fragmento HTML/js/css_, ya que de esa manera el código puede ejecutarse dentro de la propia pregunta en el navegador. Un saludo.

Comment: Pues intentando aprender coas nuevas ejeejej. E insertado el codigo pero no me deja enseñarlo ya que me salta este mensaje en rojo (Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles.)

Comment: He añadido yo tu código de la edición anterior. Sugiero que des clic en _editar_ para ver como se añade utilizando el fragmento que te mencioné. Un saludo.

Comment: Ostras vale ya me e fijado en las lineas que as añadido me lo apunto , gracias jach.

Answer (score 0):

Observaciones:

Utilizas un canvas muy grande. lo cambie por uno más pequeño (500/500);

En tu código tienes una función para dibujar un cuadrado y otra para dibujar una "matriz" que hacen exactamente lo mismo. Me he quedado solo con la que dibuja un cuadrado.

Las funciones pueden recibir argumentos así que no es necesario crear dos funciones para dibujar un cuadrado grande y uno pequeño.

Quise guardar tu código, pero habrias podido utilizar `contextoCanvas.rect()` para dibujar el cuadrado. Alternativamente podrías haberlo dibujado alrededor de un centro. Habría sido mucho más útil.

No necesitas declarar las variables `ubicacionCanvas` y `contextoCanvas` dentro de cada función. Son constantes y hay que declararlas solo una vez al inicio.

Como una recomendación de futuro: utiliza un código menos verboso. Por ejemplo en lugar de `contextoCanvas` podrías haber utilizado `ctx`.

He añadido a tu código una función que detecta la posición del ratón. En este caso el evento utilizado es `mousedown`pero la puedes utilizar con otros eventos también

```
function laPosicionDelRaton(canvas, evento) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    //devuelve un objeto
    x: Math.round(evento.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evento.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  };
}




ubicacionCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", evento => {
  //la posicion del ratón al hacer click en el canvas
  raton = laPosicionDelRaton(ubicacionCanvas, evento);
.......
```

Una vez detectada la posición del ratón necesitas comprobar si has hecho click en una casilla. Para esto hay que utilizar el método `isPointInPath`

El método `isPointInPath` detecta si el ratón se encuentra en el trazado que acabas de dibujar. Para esto necesitas volver a dibujar una por una las casillas i comprobar si el ratón esta dentro del trazado. Si encuentras la casilla sales del bucle.

Para saber si hay que dibujar un cuadrado o un circulo utilizo un contador. Si el valor del contador es un número paro dibujo un circulo, de lo contrario dibujo un cuadrado.

Espero que sea útil.

```js
/* Definición de la ubicación del canvas */
var ubicacionCanvas = document.getElementById(
  "nuestroCanvas"
); /* simplemente le decimos donde colocamos nuestro canvas es decir
yo voy aponer el contenido de nuestro canvas en esta variable*/

/* Definición del contexto del canvas (2D) */
var contextoCanvas = ubicacionCanvas.getContext(
  "2d"
); /* esto es un metodo de canvas llamado getcontext quee s para poner el contexto
osea si keremos 2d o 3d */

var radioCirculo = 30;
var elArrayDeLasCasillas = [];
var raton = {};

function dibujaCuadrado(xInicio, yInicio, longitudLado) {
  /* Definición de las propiedades de los trazos */
  contextoCanvas.strokeStyle = "black";
  contextoCanvas.lineWidth = 4;

  /*emepezamos a dibujar*/

  /* Inicio del recorrido en línea punteada */
  contextoCanvas.beginPath();
  /* Punto de inicio del trazo (x, y) */
  contextoCanvas.moveTo(xInicio, yInicio);

  /* Representación del trazo alto horizontal */
  contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio + longitudLado, yInicio);

  /* Representación del trazo derecho vertical */
  contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio + longitudLado, yInicio + longitudLado);

  /* Representación del trazo bajo horizontal */
  contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio, yInicio + longitudLado);

  /* Representación del trazo izquierda vertical */
  contextoCanvas.lineTo(xInicio, yInicio);

  contextoCanvas.closePath();
  /* Representación efectiva */
}

function dibujaCirculo(xCentroCirculo, yCentroCirculo, radioCirculo) {
  /* Definición de las propiedades de los trazos */
  contextoCanvas.strokeStyle = "black";
  contextoCanvas.lineWidth = 2;
  contextoCanvas.fillStyle = "green"; // esto es para k nos pinte el recuadro
  /*emepezamos a dibujar*/
  contextoCanvas.beginPath();
  contextoCanvas.arc(
    xCentroCirculo,
    yCentroCirculo,
    radioCirculo,
    0,
    2 * Math.PI,
    false
  );
  /*con esto nos pondra el color k le eemos dicho arriba*/
  contextoCanvas.fill();
  contextoCanvas.stroke();
}

function laPosicionDelRaton(canvas, evento) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    //devuelve un objeto
    x: Math.round(evento.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evento.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  };
}

for (linea = 1; linea <= 3; linea++) {
  /* Representación de los cuadrados de la línea numeroLinea de la matriz */
  for (columna = 1; columna <= 3; columna++) {
    
    var o = {}; //un objeto con las coordenadas del cuadrado para guardar en el array de las casillas
    o.x = columna * 100;
    o.y = linea * 100;
    o.lado = 100;

    dibujaCuadrado(o.x, o.y, o.lado); /*vale esta linea nos dibuja el cuadrado*/
    
    contextoCanvas.stroke();
    //guarda el objeto en el array
    elArrayDeLasCasillas.push(o);
  }
}

var contador = 0;//cuenta cuantas veces se hizo clic en el canvas

ubicacionCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", evento => {
  //la posicion del ratón al hacer click en el canvas
  raton = laPosicionDelRaton(ubicacionCanvas, evento);

  for (var i = 0; i < elArrayDeLasCasillas.length; i++) {
    var o = elArrayDeLasCasillas[i];
    dibujaCuadrado(o.x, o.y, o.lado);

    if (contextoCanvas.isPointInPath(raton.x, raton.y)) {
      if (contador % 2 == 0) {//para pares dibuja un circulo
        var xCentroCirculo = o.x + o.lado / 2;
        var yCentroCirculo = o.y + o.lado / 2;
        dibujaCirculo(xCentroCirculo, yCentroCirculo, radioCirculo);
      } else {//para impares dibuja un cuadrado
        var xInicio = o.x + o.lado / 4;
        var yInicio = o.y + o.lado / 4;
        var longitudLado = o.lado / 2;
        dibujaCuadrado(xInicio, yInicio, longitudLado);
        contextoCanvas.fill();
        contextoCanvas.stroke();
      }
      //incrementa el valor del contador
      contador++;
      
      //si lo has encontrado sal del bucle. No es necesario que busques más
      break;
    } 
  }

  
});
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<h1>ejercicio 2 tema 18</h1>

<canvas id="nuestroCanvas" width="500" height="500"> <!-- estoes por si el navegor es muy antiguo y no reconoce canvas-->
        Atención su navegador no soporta el elemento Canvas
</canvas>
```

Comment: Hola buenas tardes enxaneta perdona por no haber podido contestarte antes , temas de viaje y demas , tu codigo es clarisimo y al ejecutarlo desde aqui funciona como es debido e leido los comentarios que me as puesto y me han ayudado muchisimo pero a la hora de pasarlo al visual studio code  no me dibuja el canvas porque no se exactamente donde ubicar esta linea para que me la coja correctamente      canvas{border:1px solid} ,

Comment: `canvas{border:1px solid}` es irrelevante. Lo puedes poner en un elemento `<style>` o incluso como attributo `style` del canvas mismo

Comment: sisi lo e echo solo me , ya a la hora de cargar el codigo en el navegador solo me sale un recuadro negro vacio